# How to copy text from webpage and compare it in different page in selenium java webdriver

Tags: gettext

```
WebElementDetails webElementDetails = new WebElementDetails();
element = webElementDetails.getElement(webDriver, objectName, selector);
passValue = element.getText();
propertyFileReader.setValue("STORE_URL_SUFFIX", passValue);
```

I want to copy text from a reservation website and store it, then compare the same data in an email which is received as confirmation.

I tried to copy the text by using the `.getText` method, but with this I can store only one value, while I need to store multiple values.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it helped. But if i need to verify multiple values, the below code not works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Webdriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("");//Enter the website url

WebElement str1= driver.findelement(by.xpath("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").gettext();

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("");//Enter the 2nd Website you want to compare

    WebElement str2= driver.findelement(by.xpath("xxxxxxxxxxx").gettext();

    if (str1.equals.str2){
    System.out.Println("Text matched");
    }
    else{
    System.out.Println("Text not matched");
    }
```

Try the above code.